# Tableview on top of scrollview bugish behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

My project there is dropdown Tableview top of view controller.On button click I am showing that dropdown table. Now in this same view controller I have one scrollview also which is starting from exactly after dropdown button end.so my problem is when i am trying to show dropdown table it is visible behind scrollview.I use one method to bring it to front 

 `[self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.scrollView];`

so now Table is visible but when I scroll this dropdown Table that time **scrollview(behind) is scrolling instead table cell**.some top part of table is scrolling cause it is not totally covered from scrollview. Please give me suggestion for this problem ,Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

[self.view addSubview:tableview];

or

[self.view insertSubview:tableview aboveSubview:scrollview];